# PHP API not receiving any data from android app and API testing application

Tags: php, android, .htaccess, api, mod-rewrite

I've created API for android app. I've tried to send data from android app as well as some API testing application from desktop But my API is not receiving any data from those. I don't know problem is in API code or htaccess file

Below is my PHP code for API:

```
<?php
  $data = $_POST;
  print_r($data);  
?>
```

I also have use `file_get_contents("php://input");` but its not working

Output of above code is below:

> array();

Below is my htaccess file code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
            Options -MultiViews
        </IfModule>

        RewriteEngine On


    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

        # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
        RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

        # Handle Front Controller...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]



</IfModule>
```

Followign is directory path where I've saved all API files:

http://domain.com/API
API is the directory

Is there any problem in my htacess code or API

Comment: i think, change this:     <?php
  $data = $_POST["YOUR VARIABLE"];
  print_r($data);  
?>

Answer (score 0):

With API debugging, you're better of appending the debugging data to a log on the server end rather than printing the response back to the client. Something simple as this will do:

```
file_put_contents('api.log', print_r($_SERVER, true) . print_r($_POST, true), FILE_APPEND);
```

If you're using something like Cordova on Android make sure it's allowed to access your API in the whitelist. Just make sure it can make connections as you'd expect by fetching other things like random Google searches.